# Angular UI Datepicker Isn't Receiving Updated Scope Variable In Dates-Disabled Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS with the Angular UI Bootstrap.

I am running into a problem that at first I thought was a scope issue, then an initialization issue, and now I am at a loss as to what the problem is. I am posting a plunker here in the hopes that someone can help me resolve my issue.

The user case is as follows: Someone selects a donut that they want to buy. If that donut is not baked every day, then the modal pops up and prompts them to select a date to order. My problem is the datepicker doesn’t seem to know what `$scope.theActiveDonut` is, it just reverts to its default value at initialization, the cream donut, even though my console log and `angular.element($0).scope()` tell me that the `$scope.theActiveDonut` has changed. You can see this in the `console.log()`.

**My plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/rziyPLvsiiZB346qmSC5?p=preview**

As you can see, the `console.log()` reflects that the `$scope.theActiveDonut` has changed, but then from within `$scope.thingy` the `$scope.theActiveDonut`is always the Cream Donut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate controller for your $modal and send data to that controller by using

```
resolve: {
            theActiveDonut: function() { return $scope.theActiveDonut }
          }
```

when initializing the modal. Then from the modal, once the date is picked and the user clicks 'Okay' you should `modalInstanceII.close('making-a-new-one');` or if they click cancel `modalInstanceII.dismiss('canceled');`

Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/mUIfZOEqj3r0zNw5rQDB?p=preview

Comment: Why can't the modal controller be the Main Controller, as I have set it up now? If it is a scope issue, can't this still be solved within a singular controller?

Comment: When you send MainController to the modal, it instantiates a new instance of the controller and sends it a new scope. So no, it's not possible as far as I know. Plus ... with a separate controller the code is a lot cleaner than like this.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate your answer in the plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Modal instances do not share the scope of the parent controller. They have their own scope.

In order to pass a variable from the calling controller to the modal instance, use a resolve:

```
modalInstance = $modal.open({
          animation: false,
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: 'MainController',
          scope: $scope,
          size: "lg",
          resolve: {
            theActiveDonut: function() { return $scope.theActiveDonut }
          }
        });
```

Comment: FYI, the way you're determining which dates to disable in the calendar is crashing my browser. You might want to look at that logic again and come up with something more efficient.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything for me... do I have to do this on _both_ modals? The `thingy()` function still console logs the Cream Donut for me when querying `theActiveDonut`.

Comment: Yes any modal that needs to access the original "theActiveDonut" needs to have a resolve which passes it in.